# Deprecated: simplexml_load_string(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($options) of type int is deprecated

Tags: php

I just started upgrading my code to be compatible with PHP 8.2. There are several code snippets that produce an error message like this:

```
Deprecated: simplexml_load_string(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($options) of type int is deprecated in D:\Apache24\htdocs\import_php\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 365
Deprecated: simplexml_load_string(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($options) of type int is deprecated in D:\Apache24\htdocs\import_php\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 372
```

Here are the 365 and 372-line code snippets:

```
$wbRels = simplexml_load_string($this->securityScan($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels")), 'SimpleXMLElement', PHPExcel_Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions());
$xmlTheme = simplexml_load_string($this->securityScan($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "xl/{$rel['Target']}")), 'SimpleXMLElement', PHPExcel_Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions());
```

I've tried adding `(int)` in parameter 3, and the error disappears, but I'm not sure about that.

```
$wbRels = simplexml_load_string($this->securityScan($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels")), 'SimpleXMLElement', (int) PHPExcel_Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions());
```

Comment: Casting `null` to int will give you 0, and that would be the default value for the options parameter anyway (meaning, _no_ specific options get set), so I think this should be fine. (Assuming that `PHPExcel_Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions()` would return an integer to begin with, _if_ it had any options to set, because anything else would not make much sense.)

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't support PHP 8.2, please upgrade to the new version [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)